# Most elegant way to filter array by other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm basically creating a `getItemsByIds(ids)` function where `items` is an array of objects, each having an `id` key, and `ids` an array of ids.

I'm newish to ES6 so I'm sure there's a more elegant way to solve this, and since all my services will have this type of function I'd like it to be as optimal as possible. Here's what I have now:

```
getItemsByIds (ids) {
    return this.getAllItems().then(items => items.filter(item => {
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            if (item.id == ids[i]) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }));
}
```

And like I said, the `items` array is basically this:

```
[{id: 0, name: 'Foo'}, {id: 1, name: 'Bar'}, {id: 2, name: 'Baz'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn it into `ids.indexOf(item.id) > -1`.

```
getItemsByIds (ids) {
    return this.getAllItems()
    .then(items => items.filter(item => ids.indexOf(item.id) > -1));
}
```

Comment: Oh how simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `Array#indexOf`, if available to you (e.g. [polyfilled](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-includes)), is the ES2016 method `Array#includes`.

```
getItemsByIds (ids) {
    return this.getAllItems()
        .then(items => items.filter(item => ids.includes(item.id));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this too, since alex was first, and they're extremely similar solution (both very nice :) I gave him the answer.